# Left Invariant Vector field of matrix Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, vector-fields, linear-groups

In Hamilton's "Mathematical Gauge Theory" I am trying to understand this proof for the left invariant vector fields of the group $G = GL(d, \mathbb{R})$. I understand how we can assume $X\in Mat(n\times n, \mathbb{R}) = T_eG$, since an isomorphism between $T_eG$ and $Mat(n\times n, \mathbb{R})$ can be established.

[image]

what I don't quite understand how exactly we pushforward a matrix instead of a tangent vector. In addition, at the last step, I'm not sure how the derivative is supposed to be applied. As far as I understand, the symbol $\dot{\gamma}(0)$ isn't a derivative in the traditional sense, its just
notation for the tangent vector at the curve since we cant apply real analysis to a curve $\gamma : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow G$, so applying this derivative like how they want you to at the end doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer but 2 things to note. You can take the first line there as a definition of $D_e L_A$ (I assume $L_A$ is left translation by A). For the last part $\dot{\gamma}(0)$ is just $X$ by definitionso you are differentiating $A\cdot \gamma(t)$ at $t=0$ which is simply a curve of matrices. Since A is fixed, this derivative is simply $A\cdot \dot{\gamma}(0)= A \cdot X$ (chain rule but easy enough to show by hand since everything here lives in a vector space)

Comment: So as I mentioned in the last part of my question, my confusion stems from the notation of the $\dot{\gamma}(0)$. To be more clear, the way I understand this symbol is that there is an associated tangent vector $X_\gamma = \dot{\gamma}(0)$ such that $X_\gamma (f) = (f\circ\gamma)'(0)$. So to my understanding to get to the last line we would need to prove something among the lines of $X_{A\cdot\gamma} = A\cdot X_\gamma$, which I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: That property is precisely the left invariance of X

Comment: I understand that, but isn't that something we want to prove rather than state as a property?

Comment: You write "what I don't quite understand how exactly we pushforward a matrix instead of a tangent vector. " This seems a bit weird: at the beginning of your post you said yourself that $T_eG$ is isomorphic to $Mat(n \times n)$, which is another way of saying that tangent vectors look like matrices. But maybe this is not the main point of confusion?

Answer (score 2):

Okay here is an attempt at a more full answer:

You aren't pushing forward a matrix, you are pushing forward the map $L_A : G \to G; B \mapsto AB $. This is clearly a diffeomorphism of $G$ (by definition of a Lie group) and differentiating (i.e. pushforward) it at $e \in G$ gives a map $D_e L_A: T_e G \to T_AG$ which is defined by $D_e L_A (X) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}L_A(\gamma(t))$ where $\gamma$ is any curve in $G$ with $\gamma(0) = e$ and $\gamma'(0) = X$ for $X \in T_eG$. So far none of this depends on matrices anywhere, I only care how $A$ defines a diffeomorphism on G.

If we consider $G = \operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{R}) \subset M_{n\times n}$ then we can clearly identify $T_eG \cong M_{n\times n}$ but also every $T_AG \cong M_{n\times n}$ as well. Note everything is now inside a vector space so we do indeed now have things like $\gamma'(0)$ defined as the traditional derivative rather than as an abstract tangent vector to a manifold.

Now the last line is just computing the derivative of a product of curves of matrices: $A\cdot \gamma(t)$. This follows product rule as you might hope:

$$\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} (A\cdot \gamma(t)) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}A \cdot \gamma(t) +A\cdot \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\gamma(t)$$

Since $A$ is just a constant this last is just $ A \cdot \gamma'(0) = A \cdot X $

Comment: This answer makes perfect sense to me, but just to confirm with your part of the answer on everything being in a vector space, is the reason we can say that this lines up with our standard notion of our derivative because for any dim n vector space V, $V\cong\mathbb{R}^n$, so $X^a\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a} \cong X^a$

Comment: So if we take $\dot{\gamma}(t) = (f\circ \gamma)'(t) = (f\circ x^{-1}\circ x \circ \gamma)'(t) = \partial_a (f \circ x^{-1}) (x^a \circ \gamma)' = (x^a\circ\gamma)'\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}$. But we take x as a trivial chart map since the manifold is \mathbb{R}^n already, so: $ (f\circ \gamma)'(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\gamma^a\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a} \cong \frac{d}{dt}\gamma^a$

Comment: I'm confused, what is f supposed to be? Note $\dot{\gamma} = \gamma'$, the second is just easier to type. It is a standard derivative simply because it is a curve in vector space, no need for talk of charts here (except maybe at the really implicit level of defining the smooth structure on $G$). Picking coordinates, I would argue, obscures the argument.

Comment: Sorry theres a typo in that $\dot{\gamma}$ acts on a function f. so the first expression should be $\dot{\gamma}f$. Specifically the notation means that $\dot\gamma = X_\gamma$

Comment: Okay but we don't need to bring that definition of tangent vectors in here as we've already made the identification with the space of matrices. Trying to use both definitions at once I think is more confusing

Comment: Makes sense, I was just trying to reconcile the two definitions because the definition for a general manifold should reduce to the standard one when M = $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Exercise 8.14 in Loring Tu's Introduction to manifolds also has an exercise on this for M = $\mathbb{R}$ which easily generalizes to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Careful here $M$ is not a vector space in your question, it is contained in one.